# Difference beween svg & use tags and img & src (to svg image) tags

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, svg

What is the difference between showing an image with this code? :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <use xlink:href="@($"{Model.CdnUrl}/images/myImage.svg")"
</svg>
```

Or this way:

```
<img src="@($"{Model.CdnUrl}/images/myImage.svg")" />
```

*Note: The Model.CdnUrl is a CDN of AWS services (don't pay attention for it).*

So, if I want to show svg photos, what would be better and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the `<use>` as you've written it won't work ([it can't point to a complete image file, only a fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)) but the `<img>` will work as it can **only** point to a complete image file.

The `<use>` should look something like

```
<use xlink:href="@($"{Model.CdnUrl}/images/myImage.svg#someid")"
```

and then you'd have an element with id="someid" in the myImage.svg file.

Comment: Thanks, actually I just copy pased when writing the article and mistaked when pasting the use section. I also did like you wrote but just want to know the difference between both ways. When to use what...?

Comment: If your images are complete files use <img> if they are fragments use <use>